# JavaScript Regex, find all text OUTSIDE of quotations

Tags: javascript, html, regex

To clarify, I'm absolutely terrible with Regular Expressions. I've found a few examples of this on here already but I simply have no idea how to implement it for my usage.

I'm doing (rather poorly) a translation from English to French in JavaScript for a client, but I'm running into a problem where it's translating variable names and select-option values, which obviously breaks search functions and entry functions.

My existing code:

```
var englishStrings = new Array();
englishStrings[0] = /List Members/g;

var frenchStrings = new Array();
frenchStrings[0] = "Listes des membres";

$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert(language);
    if (language == "English" || language == null)
    {
        $("#language_link").text("Voir en français");
        var strNewString = $('body').html();
        strNewString = strNewString.replace(/Nccp/g, 'NCCP');
        strNewString = strNewString.replace(/Actions/g, 'Menu');
        strNewString = strNewString.replace(/Id/g, 'ID');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#language_link").text("View in English");
        var strNewString = $('body').html();
        strNewString = strNewString.replace(/Nccp/g, 'NCCP');
        strNewString = strNewString.replace(/Actions/g, 'Menu');
        strNewString = strNewString.replace(/Id/g, 'ID');
        $.each(englishStrings, function(index, value) {
            strNewString = strNewString.replace(value, frenchStrings[index]);
        });
        strNewString = strNewString.replace('Voir', 'View');
    }
    $('body').html(strNewString);
});
```

I would like to change the regex find strings (/List Members/g) to exclude quotes within the search itself, not as an afterthought as I've seen examples of.
Ex:

```
<option value="List Members">List Members</option>
```

currently becomes

```
<option value="Listes des membres">Listes des membres</option>
```

I want it to become

```
<option value="List Members">Listes des membres</option>
```

Excluding the string surrounded by quotation marks.

Again, I *know* regex is a poor choice for manipulating HTML, I regret doing it this way but we've already invested quite a bit of time doing it like this.

Comment: I'm sorry for my curiosity, but did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you may try to use something like this:

```
replace(/([^"'])List Members([^"'])/g, '$1Listes des membres$2')
```

*(or, somewhat more precise variant: `replace(/([^"'])List Members\1/g, '$1Listes des membres$1')` - will only exclude strings with matching opening and closing quotes)*

In many dialects it would be possible to do without adding backreferences to the substituting string, like so:

```
replace(/(?<!'|")List Members(?!'|")/, 'Listes des membres') # won't work in JS!
```

Here we have negative lookbehind check at the beginning and negative lookahead at the end. Unfortunately, JavaScript regex engine doesn't support lookbehind syntax, so it's only possible to implement a lookahead part of the expression:

```
replace(/List Members(?!'|")/, 'Listes des membres')`
```

This one will exclude all strings **ending** with apostrophe or quotation mark (it will not check for an opening quote at all).

And yes, regex is indeed a poor choice for manipulating HTML :)